# report sql query multiple wheres

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to write a query in sql server to grab these sample values:

```
firstname,
lastname,
count(reports where status =1),
count(reports where status =2)
```

[image: sample report]

how do I get these values in one sql statement?

here is sample output
[image]

Comment: If other column data is per-row, what exactly do you want to sum? Could you provide sample of desired result?

Comment: Still not getting it. Sum what? All reports with the same status? (and duplicate this sum for each row?). All reports with same status from same firstname/lastname? And what does `sum(all` mean?

Comment: I want the person and the amount of reports per status person,status amount 1, status amount2, status amount 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can accomplish it with a PIVOT as well. I'm not sure you would want to:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(UserName VARCHAR(10), Report VARCHAR(10), StatusId INT)
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES ('bob','report1',1)
                       ,('bob','report2',1)
                       ,('bob','report3',2)
                       ,('jim','report2',1)
                       ,('joe','report3',3)


SELECT UserName, [1] Status1_Count,[2] Status2_Count,[3] Status3_Count
  FROM (SELECT UserName
              ,StatusId
              ,COUNT(*) ReportCount
          FROM @tbl 
         GROUP BY UserName
                 ,StatusId) src
 PIVOT (MAX(StatusId) 
        FOR StatusId IN ([1],[2],[3])) pvt
```

The GROUP BY and COUNT answer is better in general, it just doesn't do what you asked for, which was to have all status counts for a user on a single one row.

Comment: This works better as it is per column and I only want certain status

Answer (score 1):

Looks like XY problem to me...

```
select firstname, lastname, status, count(status)
from report
group by firstname, lastname, status
order by firstname, lastname, status
```

Comment: It could be done with columns using common-table expression. But it is bad approach - you'll have to know what statuses are possible. With rows, it is not required.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you'll need to use a case statement

It's difficult to determine what you're going for exactly with the question, but the case statements would look something like this:

```
  sum(CASE WHEN status = 1 THEN reports ELSE 0 END),
  sum(CASE WHEN status = 2 THEN reports ELSE 0 END),
  sum(CASE WHEN status = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
  sum(CASE WHEN status = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```